# Weird screen tearing behaviour with scrolling after updating Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gedit

So I updated my self to the latest stable Nvidia driver. It is 340.32 version. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with it.

Everything is fine but if I try to scroll in some programs like for instance Gedit or just the Ubuntu Software Center, then some weird behavior happens.

Here is a link to a recording of the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bdszhpa8uivmmhb/20140909_172712.mp4?dl=0

The quality is not the best but you can see that I only scroll down one time and then the screen in Gedit starts to move up and down and also some graphical anomalies appear.

This problem does not happen with Chromium and games for instance. But stuff like Gedit is bugged for me.

Has anyone else experienced this? What could fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be related to a Compiz bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1288747

What fixed this issue for me was going back to Nvidia driver 331.38 by doing this:

(Ubuntu 14.04 x64)

1. Remove Nvidia driver:

   Ctrl-Alt-F1

   sudo service lightdm stop

   sudo sh NVIDIA*.run --uninstall
2. Remove any Noveau files (blacklist) located in /etc/modprobe.d
3. sudo reboot
4. Software & Updates, Additional Drivers, Nvidia 331.38 from nvidia-331-updates

Comment: I see. The old driver indeed fixes the problem. But as I use intensive graphical tasks also, I need to use the newer one. Will have to just wait for the Compiz patch to live then. Thank you for the anwer!

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime you can use the patched version of compiz that is provided by Christopher Townsend's PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~townsend/+archive/ubuntu/compiz-nvidia-refresh-test

Simply add the PPA and update the compiz package, then you can use the latest nvidia drivers.  Note that any updates to compiz by Canonical should be held back if you want to keep the PPA version in place.